# Selecting a JList component with a mouse and pressing Ctrl+C copies Java code

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, jcomponent

I have `JList` components that represent menu buttons. When I click on one of the buttons and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it copies this kind of information in to the clipboard

```
com.mycompany.class$6@29e3b...
```

How can I disable or prevent the user from getting that in to the clipboard when they press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>?

Comment: That information is the default toString() implementation of the object. You should override toString method in the class to whatever custom information you want to allow the user to copy to their buffer.

Comment: But in JList to toString() prints different information like index and dropPoint. Not the package name and class

Comment: I'm referring to the com.mycompany.class  This question might help you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224259/how-to-copy-jlist-element-text-to-clipboard

Comment: While it is unfortunately common for programmers to use a cell renderer to make list values or table values appear with the desired text, that is not actually the correct way to customize the displayed text.  The correct way is by having a ListModel or TableModel return objects whose toString method has the desired text (wrapping the real data, if necessary), not only to get correct clipboard behavior, but also to properly support accessibility, sorting, and keyboard navigation.